# How to create an extendable site with a JS framework (SvelteKit, Next, Angular, etc.)

Tags: javascript, npm, node-modules, svelte, sveltekit

I'm currently creating a site (in SvelteKit, but this generalizes to any framework) that will be extended into multiple different sites. The functionality is the same across all sites, but they'll have various CSS files and possibly additional components. This template is going to be used by designers, so I want to keep all the routing/data/etc. contained within my code and just allow the consumer to extend certain portions.

The main problem is that the site, of course, isn't just a module I can import. There's various dev/bundling/building tooling around it I'd like to keep, but they directly view the filesystem, so it has to somehow look to the tooling as if the project is in the main directory.

I've explored the following options, but they aren't ideal:

- Just forking the repo obviously works, but it makes upgrading difficult; I want to sandbox what the user can change and make updating to new versions easy.
- Other projects that do this (Sanity, most frameworks) implement their own CLI tool and/or custom module resolution, which I would greatly prefer not to do.

My ideal solution looks like this:

```
# What the package consumer sees:
- node_modules
- package.json (with scripts to run, build, etc.)
- src/
  - global.css
  - some-code.js

# What my code sees:
- node_modules
- package.json
- src/
  - my-code
- user-src/
  - user-code
```

but I don't know if that's possible. Any guidance as to how to do this would be appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you write and publish a npm package? Then you can install it on the consumer side and you got stuff like versioning

Comment: @JulianKleine That's what I'm trying to do; the problem is that these frameworks are meant to run as a standalone node app or on some other platform, not as a package.

Comment: When does anything ever run as a package? But if you publish a npm package, then install it in your node app, the node app can run as a standalone app